# Show infinitude of primes by number of product of factors.

Tags: proof-writing, prime-numbers

Question from book on Introductory Number theory, by Andre Weil, chapter 4, problem IV.6.

If $n, a, b,..., c$ are integers $>1$, then the number of distinct integers of the form $a^{\alpha}b^{\beta}...c^{\gamma}$  which are $\leq n$ (where
$\alpha, \beta, ...\gamma$ are positive integers) is
$\leq (1+\frac{\log n}{\log a}) (1+\frac{\log n}{\log b})  \cdots(1+\frac{\log n}{\log c})$.

Using this fact, and the fact that
$\lim_{n\rightarrow + \infty
} \frac{(\log n)^r}{n} =0$.

for every $r\gt 0$, prove that the number of primes is infinite.

(Hint: Assuming it to be finite, take for $a,b,\cdots, c$ all distinct primes.)

---

Am not clear about the question to prove infinitude of primes, as am not clear about its logic.

Request hint, how it aims to work, as there are two lemmas, with second being stated as a fact.

Considering, Lemma 1 that talks about number of product of factors $\leq n$, and this number should be less than a product of max. no. of powers possible for each factor.

If take in context of primes ( as makes it easier due to making each product of powers of primes being unique, hence easy in analysing (in rough)), then find that as minimum power of a given prime, let $a$ can be $0$, hence the
product of powers of prime is stated to be $\leq $ (power of $a=0$ + power of $a=1$ + ...+ max. power, let $m$ of $a$ such that $\lfloor  \frac {n}{a^m} \rfloor = 1) $.

It is obvious as max. power $m$ for a given prime $a$, can be : $ \frac{\log n}{\log a}= \log_an$.

The sum of all such powers from $0$ to $m$ is number of times a single factor $a$ can possibly divide $n$.

Hence, for each possible prime less than $n$, there will be some max.  power by which it divides $n$.

Also, though not a rigorous proof, the product of all such $m_i, i $ being index of max. prime dividing $n$ seems to be greater than the product of all such factors possible.

Taking a simple example, for $n=64$, have possible primes as :$ 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61$.

For each prime, the max. powers possible are:
$i=1, 2: 1+  \lfloor \log_2 64    \rfloor   = 7$
$i=2, 3: 1+ \lfloor\log_3 64\rfloor = 4$
$i=3, 5: 1+\lfloor \log_5 64\rfloor = 3$
$i=4, 7: 1+\lfloor \log_7 64\rfloor = 3$
$i=5, 11: 1+\lfloor \log_{11} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=6, 13: 1+\lfloor \log_{13} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=7, 17: 1+\lfloor \log_{17} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=8, 19: 1+\lfloor \log_{19} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=9, 23: 1+\lfloor \log_{23} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=10, 29: 1+\lfloor \log_{29} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=11, 31: 1+\lfloor \log_{31} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=12, 37: 1+\lfloor \log_{37} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=13, 41: 1+\lfloor \log_{41} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=14, 43: 1+\lfloor \log_{47} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=15, 47: 1+\lfloor \log_{47} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=16, 53: 1+\lfloor \log_{53} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=17, 59: 1+\lfloor \log_{59} 64\rfloor = 2$
$i=18, 61: 1+\lfloor \log_{61} 64\rfloor = 2$

The LHS is not practical to show for even small values of $n$, as need to compute, i.e. numbers say, $2^3.3^3.5^0.7^0.... \leq n$. Though it is a big term for small given $n=64$, and is computed easily. For this case it is: $7.4.3.3.2^{14}$.

So, request some way to prove it, theoretically.

Also, if want to show Lemma 1 true for some examples (say, for even bigger $n$, say $n= 567$), is there a suitable way to compute by combinatorics a formula for the same.

Second, is the lemma 2, that as stated in the beginning am not clear about its working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible attack plan:

- Assume $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_m$ are all the prime.
- Use the edited Lemma $1$, find an upper bound of the total number when they are expressed as prime number factorization form, call it $U(n)$.
- Since it is an upper bound, if the limit exists, $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{U(n)}{n} \ge 1$, check if you can find a contradiction.

---

Claim:

If $n$ is given and  $a_1, a_2,..., a_m$ are integers satisfying $1 <a_i \le n$ , then the number of distinct integers of the form $\prod_{i=1}^m a_i^{\alpha_i}$  which are less than or equal to $n$ where
$\alpha_i$ are nonnegative integers is upperbounded by
$ \prod_{i=1}^m(1+\frac{\log n}{\log a_i})$.

Proof:

We have $$a_j^{\alpha_j}\le \prod_{i=1}^m a_i ^{\alpha_i} \le n$$

$$0\le \alpha_j \le \frac{\log n}{\log a_j}$$

$$0\le \alpha_j \le \lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log a_j} \rfloor $$

There are $\lfloor \frac{\log n}{\log a_j} \rfloor +1$ options for $\alpha_j$.

Hence $ \prod_{i=1}^m(1+\frac{\log n}{\log a_i})$ is a valid upperbound.

---

Suppose on the contrary we have finite number of prime numbers, $p_1, \ldots, p_m$.

For any $n$ such that $n > p_m$, we have

$$n \le  \prod_{i=1}^m\left(1+\frac{\log n}{\log p_i}\right)$$

Let $U(n)$ denote the RHS.

We have $\frac{U(n)}{n} \ge 1$

However it is  clear that $U(n)=\mathcal{O}((\log n)^m)$, hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{U(n)}{n}=0$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: You are too correct, it was error in copying that caused multiplication to be replaced by addition. Hence, all the issues. But, for Lemma 2 if there can be taken some examples, before proving by the theoretical approach of L'hopital's rule and induction. Also, it is not clear how to use Lemma 1 (first fact) to prove Lemma 2.

Comment: we are not on the same page most likely. I though you are referring to $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(\log n)^r}{n}=0$.  As for the proof, try the attack plan.

Comment: Attack plan has 3 steps, first to consider divisors as primes, which have already considered ( in my example too) for the sake of ease (in absence of any combinatorics based formula, that in 'edited post' have stated need of for bigger $n$) of finding manually the product terms (as they are unique); 2nd to have a modified lemma 1 for prime number factorization (let, pnf) form, which by virtue of "Edited post" has correct lemma, and have already used pnf form; 3rd is based on working of Lemma 2 to find a contradiction, which as stated by me - is unclear to me how it intends to work.

Comment: Be cautious that $\alpha, \beta,\ldots$ that you stated are positive and not just nonnegative. Write down the corresponding  upper bound for $n$ clearly and work on it.

Comment: By, your statement of $\alpha,\beta,..., \gamma$ being positive, my above example would be waste, and am sure all values of $n$ would not have even one term in lhs. The LHS now is not even comprising of even one term, as all powers have to be positive.

I mean, if all are positive (not, non-negative), then $2^1.3^1.5^1.7^1.11.13....= 30.7.11.13....=210.11.13.... \gt 64$. It is not a prime factorization of $n=64$, but a product of all possible terms (of that took only primes as factors) that can divide $n$, and hence are less than $n$. Their product necessarily can't have all positive powers.

Comment: please avoid long comment threads. For lemma $1$ that is stated now, there is no restriction on an upper bound of $a, b, c,\ldots$, we should impose an upper bound of $n$ to use the result. We don't really need the lemma which include composite numbers in the current form, but you have to state an upper bound and then analyze the result. Perhaps stating a lemma where the indices can be nonnegative will simplify your working or you have to be more cautious if you want to use the lemma as it is stated currently.

Comment: Request that please provide code that follows my interpretation of Lemma 1, though it may not be correct. I am asking this as this would substitute for a combinatorics based formula. I hope no such formula exists, but by code can find a way.

Comment: Please help with my last request. Your code (with correct Lemma 1, for product of terms in rhs, rather than sum) is at:   https://py3.codeskulptor.org/#user306_uVPclmAUuG_16.py , but find it difficult to modify for my interpretation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123333/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-jiten).

Comment: Please be in chat. Or answer here: if change rhs upper bound to have $\prod_{i=1}^m m$, then would it still satisfy? $m$ is max. power of primes taken.

Comment: Is $n$ the count of product of $a_i$, or there is some confusion due to usage of $n$ as both the highest term as well as the count of product of terms $a_u$?

Comment: Kindly see my post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4173598/424260. Want to know also what the comment by @Ian means.

Comment: Request some help with making code (Python) for answer at: https://mathoverflow.net/a/108607/140127

Comment: Kindly respond to my last comment. Please give some hint.

Comment: Let's chat someday. I need to understand what is going on.